# Accessing a SPNEGO authenticated webservice from C#

Tags: c#, webservice-client, spnego

We have a web service that serves data over HTTP and authenticates users via SPNEGO (and single sign-on). We want to write a C# client for this web service.

Is there any standard/provided way in .NET of generating the necessary token? Extensive Googling suggests that there is no native support for SPNEGO.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows the following should do the trick:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
//SSL (https):
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
```

Comment: Op was asking for client side, the method you mentioned is for server-side